# Making 10000 HTTP requests as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, http

I need a program that needs to gather data from large list of API end points. Below is a mock-up program that attempts to make 10000 requests as fast as possible. Any suggestions on how to improve on this (especially for speed) is highly welcome. Experimentation showed that the Semaphore cap of around 100 gave the best speed.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import datetime
import time
import sys

def processData(data):
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return data

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await response.read()
        data = processData(data)
        return data

async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        return await fetch(url, session)


async def run(loop,N):
    url = "https://www.example.com"
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(100)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(N):
            task = loop.create_task(bound_fetch(sem, url, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        print("Done starting {} tasks".format(N))
        starttime = time.time()
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        responses = await  asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print("Done completing {} tasks in: {}".format(N,time.time()-starttime))

        return responses



args = sys.argv
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        N = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        N = 10000
    maintask = loop.create_task(run(loop, N))
    result = loop.run_until_complete(maintask)
    print(len(result))
```

Comment: Why do you have `time.sleep(0.001)`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That is for simulating some data-processing time.

Comment: I've flagged this question as off-topic, because you have no concrete implementation of `processData`, and provided no 'real' URL.

Comment: If `process_data` is synchronous, CPU-bound, offload it -- opt1. fetch, save, then process; opt2. fetch, push to queue, have threaded or forked workers process; opt3. use many machines :)

Comment: You could conceivably make 10K requests in parallel, but check system limits first, max number of open file descriptors, max tcp connections, network stack memory, as well as network path to your endpoints -- e.g. if your machine is behind NAT or firewall, that could have a limit.

Comment: Your questions suggests multiple endpoints, but code has only one url -- which is it? URL schema is HTTPS, which means connection establishment has a cost (latency, CPU) -- ideally you'd warm the TLS session cache in advance and reuse sessions; if it's a cold start, 10K parallel session starts are suboptimal. For your local CPU, you could spin up CORE_COUNT event loops, each in own thread/process and distribute requests across these.